# Validating Domains Using WHOIS in Bulk

Tags: c#, dns, whois

I have created an application in C# that finds Dummy Domains that ends withj .DE and then another part of the application checks them whether they really exists, the dummy are about (40 ^ 63) in number. I can successfully check them against WHOIS and everything is fine.

The question is it is taking a second to check a single domain and I am afraid how longer it will take to filter all the (40 ^ 63) domains, my whole life?

Do you have alternative?

Umair

Comment: First you want .jobs and now .de. Are you a spammer, or what else do you need this for?

Comment: No spammer, my some client first required .JOBs and now .DE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a programming question. If you meet the requirements to download a bulk copy of the whois databases, then you can simply load the entire database into RAM in a quick-lookup format of some sort, maybe B+Tree designed around caching levels, and you will have blazing fast lookup.

The whois servers impose delays on lookups to prevent people like you from running large numbers of automated lookups.

This is a variation on the theme of beginning your optimization effort by choosing a better algorithm for the job.

Comment: what do you mean by if I meet the requirements to download bulk copy of the whois databases?

Comment: I mean that the bulk copies are not accessible to just anyone. You have to ask the registry operator for access and promise not to misuse the data.